# Is there a way to measure how (non)convex a function is, maybe analogous to condition number?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the functions $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = (x+1)^2 (x-1)^2$. We know that $f$ has an infinite number of local minimizers and is nonconvex on a non-compact subset of $R$. We know that $g$ has two local minimizers and is nonconvex only on a compact subset of $R$. So, in a sense, $g$ is "closer" to being a convex function than $f$ is.

Is there some test or measure that one might use to represent this fact? I realize that one can look at the hessian and see where it is positive semidefinite, but that can get difficult to interpret, particularly if the function in question is defined on a high-dimensional space or has a complicated hessian.

Comment: One measure of convexity is _$\mu$-strong convexity_:  Fix $\mu>0$. A function $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $\mu$-strongly convex if  $f(x) - \frac{\mu}{2}||x||^2$ is convex. Now, this standard definition is only used for $\mu>0$, but you can easily apply it for $\mu<0$ to see the strength of the parabola you need to add to "convexify" a function.

Comment: You can always measure anything and everything. The only trouble is that once you've defined your would-be measure of nonconvexity, does it have any nice properties and transformation laws ? What do you do with it ? I'm afraid there isn't any such measure which is worth writing down...

Comment: @dohmatob My desire is to have some way of gauging how difficult it will be to minimize a nonconvex function. Hence my motivating example of \sin x vs. (x+1)^2 (x-1)^2. I was not aware if anyone had developed such a measure.

Comment: @dohmatob : Wow, thanks for the vote of no confidence.  I suppose the properties I had already given yesterday were "not nice," and my answer was not "worth writing down"?  It is not clear how you make such assertions.  Those properties are indeed very useful for the theory of strong convexity, I'm not sure how you conclude they are not useful more generally.  What was the purpose of your comment?

Comment: @Michael: My comment was not targeting your answer. But since you bring it up, well let's discuss it without a childish brawl. Indeed, modulus of strong-convexity can be used to in some sense measure how much one function is more convex than another, how much curvature it's graph has, etc., with favorable repercussions on rates of convergence for oracles optimizing it, etc.  These are rather well-known facts. It appears to me the OP is interested in **nonconvexity**. And once again there is no reasonable measure of the latter.

Comment: I observe the dohmatob comments use boldface for “nonconvexity” and also mention “properties and transformation laws,” yet nonconvexity was already treated in the answer (given one day before those comments), as were properties and transformation laws.  The purpose of the dohmatob comments is unclear to me, and the claim "I'm afraid there isn't any such measure which is worth writing down" seems unjustified.

Answer (score 3):

Along the lines of my previous comment: Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set. 
Motivated by the standard definition of *$\mu$-strong convexity*, we can define a (possibly nonconvex) function $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to have “convexity parameter $\mu$” if $\mu$ is the largest real number such that
$$ f(x) - \frac{\mu}{2} ||x||^2$$
is a convex function over $x \in \mathcal{X}$. Here, $||x||= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}$ is the standard Euclidean norm.

Intuitively, the value $\mu$ is the weight associated with the largest parabola that can be subtracted from $f$ while ensuring the resulting function is convex.  It can be shown that the function $f$ is convex if and only if $\mu \geq 0$.  If $\mu>0$ the function is said to be *strongly convex*. Larger values of $\mu$ correspond to "stronger" forms of convexity.

In the special case when $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}$ and the function $f$ is twice differentiable, the value $\mu$ is equal to: 
$$ \mu = -\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f’’(x) $$
and hence represents the degree of curvature of the function.

---

Examples:

1) $f(x) = \sin(x)$.   Then: 
\begin{align}
h(x) &= \sin(x) - \frac{\mu}{2}x^2\\
h'(x) &= \cos(x) - \mu x \\
h''(x) &= -\sin(x) - \mu 
\end{align}
The largest value of $\mu$ for which $h''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ is $\mu=-1$.

2) $g(x) = (x+1)^2(x-1)^2$.  Then: 
$$ g''(x) = 12x^2-4 \geq -4$$
The largest value of $\mu$ for which $g(x) - \frac{\mu}{2}x^2$ is convex is $\mu=-4$.  Thus, by this measure, this function $g$ is "more nonconvex" than the previous function $f$.

---

Some useful properties of this definition:

1) If $f$ has convexity parameter $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, then for any constants $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x) + a^Tx+b$ also has convexity parameter $\mu$.

2) If $f$ and $g$ are two functions that have convexity parameters $\mu$ and $\lambda$, respectively, then $f+g$ has convexity parameter greater than or equal to $\mu+\lambda$.

3) If $f$ has  convexity parameter $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(x) - \frac{r}{2}||x-c||^2$ is a convex function for every constant $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r \leq \mu$.

4) Suppose  $f$ is a convex function.  Fix $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f(x) + \frac{\mu}{2}||x-c||^2$ has convexity parameter greater than or equal to $\mu$.

Comment: Even though this does not match up with my motivating intuition, it is still interesting to consider. I wonder if it would be worthwhile to make your property scale-invariant. E.g., should (x+1)^2 (x-1)^2 and 2(x+1)^2 (x-1)^2 be assigned the same level of nonconvexity?

Comment: @ostrichgroomer : If you know $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has convexity parameter $-\lambda$ for some $\lambda>0$, then $f(x) + \frac{\lambda}{2}||x-c||^2$ is convex for any constant $c$ (and easier to optimize than the original $f$) and its minimizer $\tilde{x}$ satisfies $f(\tilde{x}) \leq f(x^*) + \frac{\lambda}{2}[||x^*-c||^2-||\tilde{x}-c||^2]$, where $x^*$ is the minimizer of $f$. This is particularly useful if $\mathcal{X}$ is a bounded set (so you can bound the error term proportional to $\lambda$) and/or when you have a reason to guess $c$ as a "close" point to $x^*$.