# About the convexity parameter of a multivariate function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

I have several multivariate functions to be optimized, and I wonder how I can tell which function is "good" for numerical optimization. My thought came down to the [convexity parameter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856238/is-there-a-way-to-measure-how-nonconvex-a-function-is-maybe-analogous-to-cond) $\mu$. About this topic, I got a few questions:

*1. How can I measure the convexity with the convexity parameter $\mu$ for a multivariate function?*

The convexity parameter $\mu$ is the largest real number such that
$$f\left(x\right) - \frac{\mu}{2}\left\|x\right\|^2$$
is a convex function. For a single-variate function, the convexity parameter $\mu$ is equal to
$$\mu=\sup_{x}f''\left(x\right)$$

A multivariate function is convex if and only if the Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite, right? A real symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if all eigenvalues are greater than and equal to zero, right again? So, I thought that **the convexity parameter $\mu$ of a multivariate function is the suprimum of the minimal eigenvalue of the Hessian matrix**. Is that right?

*2. Is it a fair comparison to compare the convexity parameter between the two functions in different dimensions?*

Let two different functions be
$$f:\mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R} ~~\rm{and}~~g:\mathcal{Y}\to\mathbb{R}$$
where
$$\mathcal{X}\subset \mathbb{R}^{m},~~\mathcal{Y}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n},~~\rm{and}~~\it m\ne n$$
**If $f$ has $\mu$, and $g$ has $\lambda$ for the convexity parameter, respectively, and $\mu>\lambda$, then is it possible to say $f$ is more convex than $g$?**

*3. Finally, is there any other way to say that a function is "better" to be numerically optimized?*