# Measure of function convexity

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

The functions $f(x) = x^p$, for $p>1$, are all strictly convex. But, intuitively, as $p$ grows larger, the function becomes "more convex". One can say that $f(x) = x^p$ has "convexity-level $p$".

Is there a common way to measure the convexity-level of a general convex real function? That is: is there a natural way to assign a real number to any convex function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, such that the number for $f(x) = x^p$ would be $p$, and the number would be higher for functions that are "more convex"?

Note that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1856238/29780) looks similar, but it is different, as it is about non-convex functions. I am asking about convex functions.

Comment: There is a notion of ["modulus of convexity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_and_characteristic_of_convexity) in the study of Banach spaces in functional analysis. Disclaimer: Although I love the related concepts, I still don't really understand its deep meaning.

Comment: @Surb Interesting! But it is about convexity of spaces, not functions.

Comment: Ultimately the convexity of a space is determined by the convexity of its norm, which is a function from the space to the reals.

Comment: See (v) at top of p. 177 and 4. "Pointwise Defect of Convexity" on pp. 187-194 of: Adrian Ioan Ban and Sorin Gheorghe Gal, [*On some pointwise defects of properties in real analysis*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-29/issue-1/On-some-pointwise-defects-of-properties-in-real-analysis/rae/1149860183.full), **Real Analysis Exchange** 29 #1 (2003-2004), pp. 175-197. I don't have time to say much about this (for an answer), but feel free to discuss their definitions and results as an answer yourself.